# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: tmp

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I work an application Spark-scala and I built project with sbt, my arborescence is:
 `projectFilms/src/main/scala/AppFilms`
I have 3 files in HDFS, these directories is: `hdfs/tmp/projetFilms/<my_3_Files>`, When I run my code by this command line "sbt run", it genere an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: tmp
```

and this:

```
  [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread SparkListenerBus, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.InterruptedException
```

This is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd._   

object appFilms {

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("system of recommandation").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
def main(args: Array[String]) {

val files = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://tmp/ProjetFilm/*.dat")
//val nbfiles = files.count
println("Hello my application!")
sc.stop()
}
}
```

I can't read my files from hdfs, but when i write

```
root@sandbox projectFilms# hadoop fs -cat /tmp/ProjetFilms/*
```

How I can read the content of all my files from HDFS, knowing that I work always by the same command.

Please can you answers me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the error `IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: tmp` is because in `wholeTextFiles` value its taking `tmp` as the hostname. Replace value with `hdfs:///tmp/ProjetFilm/*.dat`

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I wrote the complete path name of the HDFS files follows:  val files = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/ProjetFilm/*.dat")

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
val files = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs:///tmp/ProjetFilm/*.dat")
```

There is one additional / after `hdfs://`, which is a protocol name. You must go to `/tmp/...` via hdfs:// protocol, that's why URL needs additional /. Without this, Spark is trying to reach host `tmp`, not folder